# Setting margins with minimal header and footer

Tags: header-footer, width, dimensions, footer, pagestyle

I am working on an exam paper and am having difficulty setting up the margins. 
I need a set margin throughout the document utilizing maximum space possible.
I dont want the header and footer to be too big. Would be grateful if the margins can be defined in a way which I can change later to suit my needs. Here is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsfonts, ,color, titling,tabularx,enumitem,multirow,array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shapes.geometric}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}

\usepackage{changepage}

\makeatletter
    \newsavebox\widebox
\newenvironment{wide}
    {\@parboxrestore%
     \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\leftmargin}%
                \begin{lrbox}{\widebox}%
                \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
     }{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
     \fbox{\usebox\widebox}
     \end{adjustwidth}
     }
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}    
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

%page 1

\title{\LARGE Lautoka Muslim College\\ \LARGE Department of Mathematics and Physics}
\date{\vspace{-12ex}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}\LARGE{Term 1 Examination 2020}\end{center}
\smallskip
\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{\LARGE{Y13 MATHEMATICS}}}\\
\textit{Question Paper \& Answer Booklet}
\end{center}
 \medskip
 \begin{center}\large{Time Allowed: $3$ hours\\(\textit{An extra $10$ minutes is allowed for reading this paper})}\end{center}
\medskip
\textbf{NAME:} \rule{7cm}{0.1pt} \hspace{5cm} \textbf{YEAR:} \rule{2cm}{0.1pt} \\
\linebreak
\\
\textbf{INSTRUCTIONS}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Write your \textbf{Name} and \textbf{Year Level} on the front page. 
\item Write \textbf{all} your answers in the spaces provided
\item If you use extra sheets of paper, be sure to show clearly the question number(s) being answered and to attach each sheet securely at the appropriate places. Ensure that your \textbf{Name} and \textbf{Year Level} is written on the extra sheets.
\item Answer \textbf{all} the questions with a blue \textbf{or} black ballpoint pen or ink pen. \textbf{Do not} use red ink. You may use a pencil only for drawing. Use of \textbf{Friction Pen} is \textbf{strictly prohibited} for this exam.
\item You may use a calculator, provided it is silent, battery-operated and non-programmable.
\item Unless otherwise stated, all rounding off should be corrected to \textbf{two decimal places}. Rounding off decimal answers should be done only at the \textbf{final step}.
\item There are \textbf{$5$} questions in the paper. \textbf{All} questions are \textbf{compulsory}
\end{enumerate}
 \smallskip
\textbf{SUMMARY OF QUESTIONS}
 \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{STRAND}} & \textbf{MARKS} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}SUGGESTED TIME\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1         & Complex Numbers           & 25             & 45 MINUTES                                                         \\ \hline
2         & Vectors                   & 15             & 27 MINUTES                                                         \\ \hline
3         & Graphs of Functions       & 30             & 54 MINUTES                                                         \\ \hline
5         & Limits and Continuity     & 15             & 27 MINUTES                                                         \\ \hline
6         & Algebra                   & 15             & 27 MINUTES                                                         \\ \hline
          & \textbf{TOTAL}        & \textbf{100 MARKS}    & \textbf{180 MINUTES}                                                         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\pagebreak

%page 1 ends

%Page 2 

\textbf{STRAND 1} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \textbf{COMPLEX NUMBERS} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \hfill{\textbf{25 MARKS}}
\begin{itemize}
\item This strand has \textbf{$8$ Questions}
\item Show all working for \textbf{Questions 1-8}
\end{itemize}
\smallskip
\begin{questions}
\question A complex number is given as $z=2-\sqrt{3}i$. Find:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item $Re(z)$, the \textbf{Real} part of z \hfill{($\frac{1}{2}$ mark)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \raggedleft
        $Re(z)=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item $Im(z)$, the \textbf{Imaginary} part of z \hfill{($\frac{1}{2}$ mark)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \raggedleft
        $Im(z)=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item $\bar{z}$, the \textbf{Conjugate} of z \hfill{($\frac{1}{2}$ mark)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \raggedleft
        $\bar{z}=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm}      
\item $z+\bar{z}$\hfill{($1$ mark)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \raggedleft
        $z+\bar{z}=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{0.5cm}   
\question if $v=1-i$ and $w=5+4i$, find:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item $|w|$\hfill{($1$ mark)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \raggedleft
        $|w|=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm} 
\item $v+w$  \hfill{($1$ mark)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \raggedleft
        $v+w=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\pagebreak
%Page 3
\item $vw$\hfill{($2$ marks)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{4cm}
    \raggedleft
        $vw=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm} 
\end{enumerate}
\question Use the quadratic formula, $x=\cfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}$ to solve $x^{2}-2x=-5$ where $x\in Z$ \hfill{($3$ marks)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{10cm}
    \raggedleft
        $x=\rule[-0.5em]{1.5in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm} 
\question Let $w=\sqrt{12}+\sqrt{2}i$ 
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Find $Arg(w)$, the \textbf{Argument} of w \hfill{($1 \frac{1}{2}$ marks)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{5cm}
    \raggedleft
    $Arg(w)=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\pagebreak
\item Find $|w|$, the \textbf{modulus} of w \hfill{($1$ mark)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{7cm}
    \raggedleft
    $|w|=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item Convert $w$ into \textbf{polar} form \hfill{($1$ mark)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \raggedleft
    Polar Form$=\rule[-0.5em]{2in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item Use \textbf{De Movire's Theorem} to evaluate $w^{3}$ in rectangular form\hfill{($2$ marks)}\\
DMT : $Z^{n}=r^{n}(\cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta)$
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{9cm}
    \raggedleft
    $w^{3}=\rule[-0.5em]{2in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\end{enumerate}
\pagebreak
%Page 5
\question Express $\cfrac{1}{2-3i}$ in the form $a+bi$ \hfill{($2$ marks)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{10cm}
    \raggedleft
    $\cfrac{1}{2-3i}=\rule[-0.5em]{1in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\question Solve for $x$ and $y$ in $(-2+3i)(x+yi)=6-12i$ \hfill{($2$ marks)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{10cm}
    \raggedleft
    $\rule[-0.5em]{2in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\pagebreak
\question Represent on an \textbf{Argand Diagram}: $1<|z|\leq 3$ \hfill{($2$ marks)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{7cm}
    \raggedleft
    Graph
        \end{wide}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\question Solve the equation $z^{2}=64(\cos {90\degree} +i\sin {90\degree})$ obtaining \textbf{two} distinct complex roots.
Leave your answers in polar form. \textit{Hint}:$W_{k}=\sqrt[n]{r}(\cos \frac{\theta + 360k}{n}+i\sin \frac{\theta + 360k}{n})$ \hfill{($4$ marks)}
\begin{wide}
    \vspace{13cm}
    \raggedleft
    $w_{0}=\rule[-0.5em]{2.5in}{1pt}$\\
    \vspace{1cm} 
    $w_{1}=\rule[-0.5em]{2.5in}{1pt}$
        \end{wide}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is... not very minimal. `geometry` has parameters for all this (`left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`, `headheight`, `headsep`, `footskip`...). You should probably explain what blocks you with this package.

Comment: the thing is I dont really know how to use this package. As such requesting if someone can set the margins for me

Comment: Your document already has small margins. Due to (probably) the negative `\voffset`, there is even contents that is above the top edge of the paper sheet (not sure it is right to use `\voffset` with  `geometry`, by the way). Normally, you should start from a minimal document, read the [geometry manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) and experiment with the parameters on your minimal document until either you understand them well enough to work on your real document, or there is a parameter that you don't understand.

Comment: In the latter case, you could post the minimal document in a question here—that would make it much easier to help you and would be more in the spirit of how this site works. Sorry for not being more specific.

Comment: Note that exam places the footer BELOW \footskip rather than aligning the baselline ON \footskip.  You can use the showframe package (or showframe option of geometry) to check the placement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you may start by using the geometry with these options:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in, footskip=0.5in, tmargin=0.75in, bmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
```

You can then compile, and change the parameters until you get what you need. The options `footskip` and  `headsep` can help fine-tunning your headers and footers distances, specially when you use footnotes and headers in your documents.